# How to get 3D coordinates of a triangle on a Geodesic Dome using Python?

Tags: python, panda3d

I want to generate a Geodesic Dome (sphere) with triangles using the panda3d engine.
I have searched in python for a function to position my all triangles in 3d world (x,y and z) and rotation to create the sphere.
[image]

For rotation i use function setHpr(0,0,0)
H for heading
p for pitch
r for roll

I have search for a mathematical function to replace my 0 values in:

```
class Triangle(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, h, p, r):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.x = h
        self.y = p
        self.z = r  

Triangle_List=[]        
for i in range(0,2000):
    mytriangle=Triangle(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    Triangle_List.append(mytriangle)
```

How can I transform the Triangle(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) coordinates to the required values ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The usual way is to start with an [icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron#Spherical_coordinates) and then subdivide its faces & project the new points from the centre to the surface of the sphere, as illustrated [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Geodesic_icosahedral_polyhedron_example.png/320px-Geodesic_icosahedral_polyhedron_example.png).

Answer (score 0):

The concepts to subdivide the faces and project to new points are described in the blog
[designing a geodesic house (part 1)](https://badassdatascience.com/2012/04/15/geodesic-dome-design-part-1/). A more thorough treatment is the book *Geodesic Math and How to Use It* by Hugh Kenner 1976.

[PyDome](https://badassdatascience.com/2013/12/05/pydome-a-geodesic-dome-designer/) will provide the coordinates for many types of geodesic dome configurations. Python [Code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pydome/source/default/source) on GitHub.

Rick Bono's [DOME Program](http://www.antiprism.com/other/dome/index.html) written in C++ has extensive documentation and features.

[Acid Dome](http://acidome.ru) is one online calculator that provides the templates for edges and faces, but not the coordinates.